# Extjs Chart Series ItemClick in Controller

Tags: extjs, controller, series

I am creating a itemclick event of chart series items in extjs

```
        "mychart series": {
            itemclick: function() {
                alert('s');
            }
        }
```

The above function does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Chart series is not a Component, and so the selector never matches. You need to relay Series events as if they were fired by the Chart itself, and match against the Chart:

```
Ext.define('My.Chart', {
    extend: 'Ext.chart.Chart',
    alias: 'widget.mychart',

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        me.callParent();

        me.series.each(function(s) {
            // This will relay Series `itemclick` event
            // as `seriesitemclick` fired on the Chart itself
            me.relayEvents(s, ['itemclick'], 'series');
        });
    }
});

Ext.define('My.Controller', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    init: function() {
        this.control({
            mychart: {
                seriesitemclick: this.onSeriesItemClick
            }
        });
    },

    onSeriesItemClick: function(item) {
        var sprite = item.sprite,
            series = item.series,
            record = item.storeItem,
            value  = item.value;

        ...
    }
});
```